# Check if Postgres JSON multidimensional array contains specific string value

Tags: postgresql

Good day,

I've found a couple solutions on S.O pertaining to finding rows with its JSON column having a specified value.

The issue I'm currently facing, is that my specific JSON column (`session_data`) contains a multidimensional array, with one or several values:

```
{
    "lastMessages": [
        {
            "eventId": "1",
            "replyDate": "2022-11-23T05:47:18.577Z",
            "replyPreview": "response-text-a"
        },
        {
            "eventId": "2",
            "replyDate": "2022-11-23T05:48:14.550Z",
            "replyPreview": "response-text-b"
        },
        {
            "eventId": "3",
            "replyDate": "2022-11-23T06:23:53.234Z",
            "replyPreview": "response-text-c"
        },
        {
            "eventId": "4",
            "replyDate": "2022-11-23T06:24:13.555Z",
            "replyPreview": "response-text-d"
        },
        {
            "eventId": "5",
            "replyDate": "2022-11-23T06:24:30.919Z",
            "replyPreview": "response-text-z"
        }
    ],
    "workflows": {},
    "slots": {}
}
```

How would I go about retrieving all rows from a table where the JSON column array's `replyPreview` property contains the value `response-text-z`?

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM dialog_sessions WHERE (session_data->'lastMessages')::jsonb ? 'response-text-z' LIMIT 100
```

however to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JSON path expression:

```
select *
from dialog_sessions 
where session_data @? '$.lastMessages[*].replyReview == "response-text-z"'
```

If you are on an older Postgres version you can try the `@>` operator:

```
select *
from dialog_sessions 
where session_data -> 'lastMessages' @> '[{"replyPreview": "response-text-z"}]'
```

[DbFiddle using Postgres 11](https://dbfiddle.uk/LtVUrSM6)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. Upon trying the query, I get the following error:

ERROR:  operator does not exist: json @? unknown

Comment: @RookieSA: then you are using and older Postgres version. See my edit for an alternative

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. I've tried your suggestion, however this too seems to return an error, stating that the operator '@>' does not exist. I'm using v11.17 for its compatibility with Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Well, the operator `@` does not exist indeed. But I used `@>`

Comment: Thank you. I've accepted your answer, as it has provided the solution. All I've had to do was explicitly typecast the `session_data` column to jsonb, as the column itself is of json type.

Comment: @RookieSA: `jsonb` is the recommended data type to store JSON values. You should convert the column to `jsonb` permanently.